# Owner of Amazon EC2 instance / volume / snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was wondering if there is any way of finding out what user credentials were used when an instance / volume / instance is created in Amazon AWS EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [enable CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/using-cloudtrail.html), you can see information about API calls made with your AWS account. CloudTrail will stash json-formatted log files into a specified S3 bucket for you.

Here's a snippet of user metadata from the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/event_reference_top_level.html) where an IAM User named Alice made a request:

```
"userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice",
        "accountId": "123456789012",
        "accessKeyId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
        "userName": "Alice",
        "sessionContext": {
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                "creationDate": "2014-03-18T14:29:23Z"
            }
        }
```

You can find further information on the userIdentity element in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/event_reference_user_identity.html).

For finding who created an instance, volume or snapshot... you'll want to search for [eventName](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/event_reference_record_body.html) elements (this element describes the requested API action) that match:

- [RunInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html)
- [CreateVolume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateVolume.html)
- [CreateSnapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSnapshot.html)

Comment: I needed something for pre-CloudTrail, but this is useful too. Thanks!